# Prove a holomorphic function is constant if it satisfies an integral inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$,
> $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n$ be its Taylor expansion about
> $z=0$. Show that if there exists $M>0$ s.t
> $$\iint\limits_{\overline{D}(0,R)}|f(x+iy)|^2dxdy\leq M,\quad\forall
>  R>0$$ then $f$ is constant.

My attempt:
I already proved the following equality $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta,\quad\forall r>0.$$
Let set $x+yi=re^{i\theta}\Rightarrow dx=rie^{i\theta}d\theta$.
So we have $$\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{x^2+y^2=R}|f(x+yi)|^2\dfrac{-y-ix}{x^2+y^2}dx.$$
I don't know how to continue. Could some help me or have another way to deal with the problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Multiply $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2r^{2n}=\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta$ by $r$ and integrate w.r.t. $r$  from $0$ to $R$

Answer (score 0):

Jacobian of the transformation given by $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$ is $r$.

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}|a_n|^2R^{2n}/(2n+1)=\int_0^{R}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}|f(re^{i\theta})|^2d\theta rdr =\int_{|z| \le R} |f(x+iy)|^{2}dxdy\le M$. This is true for all $R>0$ and letting $R \to \infty$ we see that $a_n=0$ for all $n >0$.

Comment: Could you explain why you have that "recall"?

Comment: I am converting an integral from rectangular  coordinates to polar coordinates.

Comment: @AlexNguyen When you change the variables from  $x,y$ to $r,\theta$ you have to multiply by the Jacobian of the transformation.